# Is it possible to add a custom element as a 'form element' in angularJs so to take advantage of ng-dirty and ng-pristine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a form which includes a sortable list. The user can add, remove and move elements in this list. Whenever a change is made to this list, I would like to change the from to be dirty.

I can achieve this by watching each action performed on the list an executing the `$scope.formname.$setDirty();` method, but I was wondering if there is a custom directive to do this.

For example, I have the following dom:

```
<div class='my-list'>
    <ul class='sortable-list'>
        <li>
            List Item 1
        </li>
        <li>
            List Item 2
        </li>
        <li>
            List Item 3
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This list is within a form and stored as a list in the model. I think what I want to do is set a watcher on this list and set the form state to dirty when it changes, then pristine when the form is stored (may just have answered my own quenstion...)

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what you want to achieve - if I understand correctly (presumably you want some visual notification if a field is empty/required), you don't *need* a directive to do this. You can do this with pure angular templates, eg on a parent element: `ng-class="{ 'invalid': myform.someField.$pristine || myform.someField.$invalid }"`

Comment: Thanks, yes don't think I explained it well. I have added more information and think I have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This was achieved by using:

```
     $scope.$watch(function () { return sequence.myList}, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    // logic to check for change
                    $scope.formname.$setDirty();
     });
```

where sequence is the service storing the state of the section of the form.